# Getting request parameters on Slim

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to get request parameter names and values dynamically, but the array is always empty. This is the get route:

```
$app->get('/get/profile/:id_user', function ($id_user) use ($app) {
    print_r($app->request()->params());
});
```

And this is how im calling it from the browser:

```
http://localhost/get/profile/9492
```

This should return an array with `id_user => 9492`but it comes empty.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Notice:** Please read update notes before trying out this code.  The update note is my first comment in this answer.

Couldn't get to test it but please try the following:

```
$app->get('/get/profile/:id_user', function ($id_user) use ($app) {
    $req = $app->request();
    print_r($req->params());
});
```

Reference documentation: http://docs.slimframework.com/#Request-Method

**Update:** Okay after some digging figured the following, the `params()` method requires a parameter. If called without a parameter a Notice is raised. Checking the source revealed that this function called without a parameter returns null. See `Http/Request.php` line 199. Also for some reason currying does not seem to work either to retrieve parameters so you have to use the function parameter `$id_user` which has the expected value.

Comment: No results neither :( ... `Array ( )` is the only response.

Comment: Okay after some digging figured the following, the `params()` method requires a parameter.  If called without a parameter a Notice is raised.  Checking the source revealed that this function called without a parameter returns null.  See `Http/Request.php line 199`.  Also for some reason currying does not seem to work either to retrieve parameters so you have to use the function parameter `$id_user` which has the expected value.

Comment: So, there is no way to dynamically grab all the requested parameters. The documentation is kind of vaguely written in that matter, but thanks for the explanation! I'll vote for your answer as the solution, but it would be nice if you add the notice in the post for other people hehe.

Comment: @andufo, sure.  I added the notice and added my comment in the update notes.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @andufo, notice you can use $app->request->get() to retrieve them.  See http://docs.slimframework.com/#Request-Variables

Answer (score 3):

You can use following:

```
$app->get("/test.:format/:name",function() use ($app){
  $router = $app->router();
  print_r($router->getCurrentRoute()->getParams());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for the past half hour :)

Answer (score 0):

Also is a configuration problem。

try

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```