# Getting more than one request parameter on Slim

Tags: php, get, slim

Using slim I can do a GET method like the one here [Getting request parameters on Slim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056281/getting-request-parameters-on-slim), so `function($id)` uses the single `$id` parameter passed in the URL (`/getpropfile/:id`), but I'd like to know how to do this with two parameters, so `/:username/:password`

Would `function()` have to have more than one parameter, so `function($username, $password)`?

Note: I just want it to echo `$username` and `$password` so I know the two parameters have been passed in.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems I answered my own question...

```
$app->get('/:username/:password', function ($username, $password) use ($app) {
    //function to return the username and password
    $result = getUserByUsernameAndPassword($username, $password);
    $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    echo $result;
});
```